# In woocommerce, what determines the order_item_id?

Tags: unique, product, woocommerce

I've got a webshop running with woocommerce. The webshop has products with variations. When I add the same product with the same variation, I want it to generate a new order_item_id, in stead of combining the two under the same order_item_id.

I can't seem to find the bit of code that is responsible for generating the order_item_id.

Could anyone tell me where this bit of code is located?

My goal is to make each product unique in stead of stacking items that are the same.

-EDIT

Ok, so I've narrowed it down to class-wc-cart.php

On line 782 the product ID is generated with the following code:

```
public function generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id = '', $variation = '', $cart_item_data = array() ) {

        $id_parts = array( $product_id );

        if ( $variation_id ) $id_parts[] = $variation_id;

        if ( is_array( $variation ) ) {
            $variation_key = '';
            foreach ( $variation as $key => $value ) {
                $variation_key .= trim( $key ) . trim( $value );
            }
            $id_parts[] = $variation_key;
        }

        if ( is_array( $cart_item_data ) && ! empty( $cart_item_data ) ) {
            $cart_item_data_key = '';
            foreach ( $cart_item_data as $key => $value ) {
                if ( is_array( $value ) ) $value = http_build_query( $value );
                $cart_item_data_key .= trim($key) . trim($value);
            }
            $id_parts[] = $cart_item_data_key;
        }

        return md5( implode( '_', $id_parts ) );
    }
```

Now all that is left is to edit in a unique ID via a timestamp or something.
Will keep you guys posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. 
Open class-wc-cart.php, and add a timestamp, or anything else that is unique to $id_parts.

Just like in the following code:

```
public function generate_cart_id( $product_id, $variation_id = '', $variation = '', $cart_item_data = array() ) {

    $id_parts = array( $product_id );

    if ( $variation_id ) $id_parts[] = $variation_id.time();

    if ( is_array( $variation ) ) {
        $variation_key = '';
        foreach ( $variation as $key => $value ) {
            $variation_key .= trim( $key ) . trim( $value );
        }
        $id_parts[] = $variation_key.time();
    }

    if ( is_array( $cart_item_data ) && ! empty( $cart_item_data ) ) {
        $cart_item_data_key = '';
        foreach ( $cart_item_data as $key => $value ) {
            if ( is_array( $value ) ) $value = http_build_query( $value );
            $cart_item_data_key .= trim($key) . trim($value);
        }
        $id_parts[] = $cart_item_data_key.time();
    }

    return md5( implode( '_', $id_parts ) );
}
```